# ipv6 multicast support in sharpsnmplib for discovery

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

I'm using **Lextm.SharpSnmpLib**(v10.0.5) to discover and retrieve information of the devices. It's working fine for IPv4 discovery, using broadcast. But if I use IPv6 multicast to link-local addresses, I'm getting **"IPv6 is not yet supported"** exception from the **DiscoveryAsync** method in library.

So I modified this function's implementation to support IPv6. This works fine for IPv6 discovery. We are planning to use this source code changes in our application.

Let us know if this library can be modified, If Yes, share any conditions to follow.

Comment: Is it really that difficult for you to locate the documentation for this library, which includes sections on both the licenses under which releases are made *and* how to contribute back to it?

Comment: is it possible to share the sample source with IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [project](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib) is [licensed](https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/blob/master/LICENSE) under the MIT license.

To quote the page:

> A short and simple permissive license with conditions only requiring preservation of copyright and license notices. Licensed works, modifications, and larger works may be distributed under different terms and without source code.

So you are perfectly fine to follow the terms of the license, for example fork the project and make your modifications and then use your fork in the future. If you want to be nice, create a pull request for the maintainer and explain you changes, so everybody can use the improved version.